Trying to connect via Power BI to my database on SQL Server 2016 results in this error: SSL Provider, error: 0
We receive the following error message when trying to connect via Power BI to my database on SQL Server 2016:

“SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.”

When I run the application it's perfect. But when the user runs the application, he gets the message above.
It seems to point toward certificates, but why don't I receive the error message when run as myself?

It sounds like your system trusts a CA that the user's system doesn't trust, and a server (I'm guessing the SQL server) is presenting a cert chain anchored in a CA that the user's system doesn't trust.

Are you and 'the user' both running on the same Windows? Windows has per-userid cert stores -- an 'authority' (CA) cert could be in the cert store for your userid but not for that of 'the user'.

The quick-fix when you have an untrusted certificate (self-signed?)
is to add Encrypt=false to your connection-string.
This is required, since recent SQL Server versions made
Encrypt=true the default, which means that a trusted certificate
is required.
The best and safest fix is to use
Let's Encrypt
to get a CA-signed certificate from a known trusted CA for free.
You will find much more information in the post
"The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when connecting DB in VM Role from Azure website.
